# get selectedValue() of dropDownList after setting the value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a databound dropdownlist on a page, where in the page_load I set the selectedValue (inside a 'not isPostBack').

Although the page displays fine and shows the correct item as selected.. inside the page_load if I try and get the selectedValue() and display it to the screen, I always get null... selectedIndex is -1.

I have a button, which when clicked refers to this ddl's selectedValue, and here it pulls through the the expected result.. so how come I can't see it immediately after setting it, while still in page_load?

cheers :)

edit: the code..

ddl declaration

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dlCountryList" DataSourceID="dsCountryList"
                DataValueField="countrylistid" DataTextField="description">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and the page_load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     dlCountryList.SelectedValue = "GR"
     Response.Write("*" + CStr(dlCountryList.SelectedIndex) + "*")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you paste the markup of the dropdown list and the section of C#/VB code from Page_Load?

Comment: Try manually calling the dll DataBind() method after setting the selected value.

Comment: @shadow wizard - thank you! that does the trick.. but what fundamentals am I missing that makes me wonder why that works? Is databind() being called implicitly elsewhere, which allows my button to access the correct selectedValue()?

Comment: cheers, glad it's working.. see my answer for more details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually call the DataBind() method of the drop down after setting the selected value.

The SelectedValue is not ordinary get/set property of the control, by setting it you only set some "flag" that is used when the drop down is binded.

By default it's binded after the Page_Load event (not sure which event exactly) but it's also possible to call it manually.

Comment: Thank you :) simple enough I just need to remember it!

Comment: @Tabloo no problem.. after some digging with Reflector I saw that setting the SelectedValue assign the Selected property of the proper Item in the drop down as true, however it's not setting the SelectedIndex of the drop down, and the SelectedValue getter is simply: `return this.Items[selectedIndex].Value` (of course it check before that selectedIndex is not -1)  so it explains why it's always null.

Comment: I had assumed this was a page lifecycle issue -- nice discovery!

Comment: @jwiscarson also page life cycle, as the SelectedIndex is being set at some point. :)